# Generating database from entity framework model

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm planning on making an entity framework class that will contain several models, Those models will create the database table structure.

Did some work and came up with this model structure:

```
public class Search
{
    public int SearchId { get; set; }
    public string SearchName { get; set; }
    public Times t { get; set; }
    public Media m { get; set; }

}


public class Times
{
    public int TimesId { get; set; }
    DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    String Days { get; set; }
    List<HourSlice> TSlist;
}

public class HourSlice
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Slice { get; set; } // will contain both -from hour- and -to hour- slice

}



public class Media
{
    int MediaId { get; set; }
    List<OperatorType> ot;
    List<Operator> op;
    List<Program> p;
    List<Sector> s;
    List<Categorie> cat;
    List<MisradPirsum> mp;
}

public class OperatorType
{
    int OperatorTypeID { get; set; }
    string OperatorTypeName { get; set; }
}

public class Operator
{
    int OperatorID { get; set; }
    string OperatorName { get; set; }

}

public class Program
{
    int ProgramID { get; set; }
    string ProgramName { get; set; }
}

public class Sector
{
    int SectorID { get; set; }
    string SectorName { get; set; }
}

public class Categorie
{
    public int CategorieId { get; set; }
    List<Branch> br;
    List<SubBranch> sbr;
    List<SubSubBranch> ssbr;

}

public class Branch
{
    int BranchID { get; set; }
    string BranchName { get; set; }
}

public class SubBranch
{
    int SubBranchID { get; set; }
    string SubBranchName { get; set; }

}

public class SubSubBranch
{
    int SubSubBranchID { get; set; }
    string SubSubBranchName { get; set; }
}

public class MisradPirsum
{
    public int MisradPirsumId { get; set; }
    List<Company> c;
}

public class Company
{
    int CompanyID { get; set; }
    string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

The initiator on Global.asax:

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBS"].ConnectionString);
        Database.SetInitializer<DBS>(new Search_Initializer());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

     // Database.SetInitializer<PlayWithMVC4.Models.DBS>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PlayWithMVC4.Models.DBS>());
        Database.SetInitializer<PlayWithMVC4.Models.DBS>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PlayWithMVC4.Models.DBS>());

    }
```

The Search class is the parent of all other classes as you can see.
Underneath it the Times table that will relate to the Hourslice table.
The Media table is also underneath the Search class and it has 6 tables underneath it, Several has their own child tables, each parent has it's own ID.

The main goal is to create a search database that will have all possible data structure to save searches and interact with the original data-database to get the actual data of each search properties/parameters.

I'm having problem creating the database with this error:
"error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 30:No mapping specified for properties Search.m in Set Searches.\r\nAn Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:\r\n  Entity is type [PlayWithMVC4.Models.Search]\r\n"}"

I'm sure something has done wrong with the structure/logic, But I'm not sure where to start digging, Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you want to ensure that all of the properties that you are mapping are public and that they are actually properties and not fields.

The members on your `Media` type for example are all private as you haven't specified a public access modifier. The collection members are also fields, not properties, as they have no getters and setters.

Also, if you wish to support proxy types for change tracking or lazy loading, then have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the full list of requirements.